# PHP RegEx split to 2D array?

Tags: php, regex

Is it possible to convert the following string in to an array with PHP and preg_match_all, e.g;

The string will always be one character and a number followed by a space.

```
String: "C1 X2 B10"

$array[0][type]=>"C"

$array[0][number]=>1

$array[1][type]=>"X"

$array[1][number]=>2

$array[2][type]=>"B"

$array[2][number]=>10
```

Comment: you don't really need regex to do this... you can just explode the string on " " (space) and then separate the letters from the numbers and create your array :)

Comment: I have modified my original question and added what variations the string will be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use named groups in your regex:

```
$str = "C1 X2 B10";
$re = '~(?P<type>[A-Z])(?P<number>\d+)~';
preg_match_all($re, $str, $m, PREG_SET_ORDER);
print_r($m);
```

which gives you

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => C1
            [type] => C
            [1] => C
            [number] => 1
            [2] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => X2
            [type] => X
            [1] => X
            [number] => 2
            [2] => 2
        )

     etc
```

so you can use `$m[1]['type']` directly.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you can always use the regex for this which is WAAAAY faster, but I wanted to show you that you can do it without regex. There are more ways to solve a problem. As Harvey Specter, the character from "Suits" would say: *"If someone points a gun to your head, there are 146 ways you can defend yourself"* ;)

Here... try this:

```
$string = 'C1 X2 B10';

$explode = explode(' ', $string);

$i = 0;
foreach ($explode as $exp){
    $number = substr($exp, 1);
    $letter = substr($exp, 0, 1);
    $array[$i]['type'] = $letter;
    $array[$i]['number'] = $number;

    $i++;
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($array);
echo '</pre>';
```

the output will be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [type] => C
            [number] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [type] => X
            [number] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [type] => B
            [number] => 10
        )

)
```

**WARNING!!** This solution will work only if you have only 1 letter, only at the beginning, with space separated elements in the string!

Hope this helps! :D

Comment: thanks, this works, would be nice to use regex but this is definitely a working alternative.

Comment: :) glad to help! Please accept the answer so the question can be marked as [solved] by SO mods :)

Comment: Unfortunately its not solved as I would like to do this with a regex expression, the mods seem to have removed that part of the question!

Comment: So let me get this straight... you come here with a question, without passing any code, NOTHING that you tried, I give you an answer that CLEARLY solves your problem and you have the nerve to ask ME or ANYONE ELSE to make it with a REGEX FOR YOU? :)))) you must be out of your mind, I swear... And if someone DOES do that for you, in my opinion, they must be stupid as HELL! Get out of here you lazy son of a...

Comment: I have tried many regex expressions with preg_match_all() but I have no idea where to start having never used regex before. I simply asked if it was possible and to be pointed in the right direction. I gave you thanks for your solution as it does the job, but I did state in my original question that I would prefer regex. Get off your high horse...

Comment: High horse? Are you kidding me? :)) Look at your question... you have 37 views and only one answer... MINE! look at the comments... Do you see people lining up to help you with this? No! You know why? Because first of all, you question does not comply with SO guidelines of how to ask a question. And I know that, but I didn't cared, because I wanted to help you. And know you feed me this BS? Keep on moving. Give some code to start off with, or ask google!